# How to add a confidence interval to a PsychoPy RatingScale?

Tags: python, scale, rating, psychopy

I am programming a task in PsychoPy (version 1.84.2), where participants have to rate the contrast difference between some gratings (e.g. a value between -1 and 1). I designed a rating scale using visual.RatingScale. Now I wanna ask the participants to add two more markers to the scale indicating their confidence interval. OR even better: participants could use the scroll wheel of the mouse to adapt the width of the interval.

Is there any possibility to do this??

Code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division
from psychopy import locale_setup, gui, visual, core, data, event, logging, sound
from psychopy.constants import (NOT_STARTED, STARTED, PLAYING, PAUSED,
                                STOPPED, FINISHED, PRESSED, RELEASED, FOREVER)
import numpy as np  # whole numpy lib is available, prepend 'np.'
from numpy import (sin, cos, tan, log, log10, pi, average,
                   sqrt, std, deg2rad, rad2deg, linspace, asarray)
from numpy.random import random, randint, normal, shuffle
import os  # handy system and path functions
import sys  # to get file system encoding

# Ensure that relative paths start from the same directory as this script
_thisDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
os.chdir(_thisDir)

# Store info about the experiment session
expName = u'rating'  # from the Builder filename that created this script
expInfo = {'participant':'', 'session':'001'}
dlg = gui.DlgFromDict(dictionary=expInfo, title=expName)
if dlg.OK == False:
    core.quit()  # user pressed cancel
expInfo['date'] = data.getDateStr()  # add a simple timestamp
expInfo['expName'] = expName

# Data file name stem = absolute path + name; later add .psyexp, .csv, .log, etc
filename = _thisDir + os.sep + u'data/%s_%s_%s' % (expInfo['participant'], expName, expInfo['date'])

# An ExperimentHandler isn't essential but helps with data saving
thisExp = data.ExperimentHandler(name=expName, version='',
    extraInfo=expInfo, runtimeInfo=None,
    originPath=None,
    savePickle=True, saveWideText=True,
    dataFileName=filename)
# save a log file for detail verbose info
logFile = logging.LogFile(filename+'.log', level=logging.EXP)
logging.console.setLevel(logging.WARNING)  # this outputs to the screen, not a file

endExpNow = False  # flag for 'escape' or other condition => quit the exp

# Start Code - component code to be run before the window creation

# Setup the Window
win = visual.Window(
    size=(1280, 800), fullscr=True, screen=0,
    allowGUI=True, allowStencil=False,
    monitor='testMonitor', color=[0,0,0], colorSpace='rgb',
    blendMode='avg', useFBO=True)
# store frame rate of monitor if we can measure it
expInfo['frameRate'] = win.getActualFrameRate()
if expInfo['frameRate'] != None:
    frameDur = 1.0 / round(expInfo['frameRate'])
else:
    frameDur = 1.0 / 60.0  # could not measure, so guess

# Initialize components for Routine "trial"
trialClock = core.Clock()
rating = visual.RatingScale(win=win, name='rating', marker=u'triangle', size=1.0, pos=[0.0, 0.0], low=-1, high=1, labels=["-1","1"], precision=100, showValue=True, scale=None)

# Create some handy timers
globalClock = core.Clock()  # to track the time since experiment started
routineTimer = core.CountdownTimer()  # to track time remaining of each (non-slip) routine 

# ------Prepare to start Routine "trial"-------
t = 0
trialClock.reset()  # clock
frameN = -1
continueRoutine = True
# update component parameters for each repeat
rating.reset()
# keep track of which components have finished
trialComponents = [rating]
for thisComponent in trialComponents:
    if hasattr(thisComponent, 'status'):
        thisComponent.status = NOT_STARTED

# -------Start Routine "trial"-------
while continueRoutine:
    # get current time
    t = trialClock.getTime()
    frameN = frameN + 1  # number of completed frames (so 0 is the first frame)
    # update/draw components on each frame
    # *rating* updates
    if t >= 0.0 and rating.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        rating.tStart = t
        rating.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        rating.setAutoDraw(True)
    continueRoutine &= rating.noResponse  # a response ends the trial
    
    # check if all components have finished
    if not continueRoutine:  # a component has requested a forced-end of Routine
        break
    continueRoutine = False  # will revert to True if at least one component still running
    for thisComponent in trialComponents:
        if hasattr(thisComponent, "status") and thisComponent.status != FINISHED:
            continueRoutine = True
            break  # at least one component has not yet finished
    
    # check for quit (the Esc key)
    if endExpNow or event.getKeys(keyList=["escape"]):
        core.quit()
    
    # refresh the screen
    if continueRoutine:  # don't flip if this routine is over or we'll get a blank screen
        win.flip()

# -------Ending Routine "trial"-------
for thisComponent in trialComponents:
    if hasattr(thisComponent, "setAutoDraw"):
        thisComponent.setAutoDraw(False)
# the Routine "trial" was not non-slip safe, so reset the non-slip timer
routineTimer.reset()
# these shouldn't be strictly necessary (should auto-save)
thisExp.saveAsWideText(filename+'.csv')
thisExp.saveAsPickle(filename)
logging.flush()
# make sure everything is closed down
thisExp.abort()  # or data files will save again on exit
win.close()
core.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's available back in version 1.84 (or why you need to use such an old version of PsychoPy), but the general advice now would be to avoid using the `RatingScale` class and instead use the simpler but more extensible `Slider` class.

Regardless, what I'd suggest is that you avoid modifying that object by adding extra markers and so on. Instead create and draw a separate rectangular `ShapeStim` object:
https://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/shapestim.html

Set the vertical position of that rectangle to be a constant, either above, below, or behind the slider as required. On each frame, set its centre to correspond to the marker value of the slider or rating scale. Monitor the mouse scroll wheel, and use that to control the length of the rectangle, to indicate the uncertainty width.